# colcon build --symlink-install can't find '__main__' module; ld: cannot find -lpthreads

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Fedora 32, ROS 10.1, following [these instructions](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Development-Setup/#install-dependencies-using-rosdep), running `colcon build --symlink-install` errors out with the below:

```
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/em'
CMake Error at cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):

  execute_process(/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/bin/python"
  "/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/em" "--raw-errors"
  "-F"
  "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/pkg.develspace.context.pc.py"
  "-o" "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/devel/lib/pkgconfig/catkin.pc"
  "/root/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/cmake/em/pkg.pc.em") returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  cmake/catkin_package.cmake:327 (em_expand)
  cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (catkin_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Failed   <<< catkin [0.82s, exited with code 1]
```

log file:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_210d5.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_210d5] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_210d5/fast] Error 2

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_d2cba/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_d2cba
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_d2cba  -lpthreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d2cba.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_d2cba] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_d2cba/fast] Error 2
```

Is this a known issue? Is there a work around for the`pthreads`? I also tried with  `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` no difference.

Edit: after adding setuptools and pytest-cov here are the errors:

```
Failed   <<< cyclonedds [0.56s, exited with code 1]


Performing C SOURCE FILE Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_473c5/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/src.c.o   -c /root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
Linking C executable cmTC_473c5
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD    CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_473c5
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/src.c.o: in function `main':
src.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/usr/bin/ld: src.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_473c5.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_473c5] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_473c5/fast] Error 2


Source file was:
#include <pthread.h>

void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_b1ea7/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_b1ea7
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_b1ea7  -lpthreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_b1ea7.dir/build.make:107: cmTC_b1ea7] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/root/ros2_dashing/build/cyclonedds/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:141: cmTC_b1ea7/fast] Error 2
```

Edit 3:

```
-- stderr: cyclonedds
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Java (missing: Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE
  Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE) (found suitable version
  "1.8.0_265", minimum required is "1.8")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake:332 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/idlc/cmake/IdlcGenerate.cmake:12 (find_package)
  src/idlc/CMakeLists.txt:44 (include)


---
Failed   <<< cyclonedds [3.19s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp [3.52s]
Aborted  <<< ament_flake8 [0.78s]
Aborted  <<< ament_pyflakes [0.74s]
Aborted  <<< ament_cmake_core [0.85s]
Aborted  <<< fastcdr [3.56s]

Summary: 8 packages finished [6.55s]
  1 package failed: cyclonedds
  5 packages aborted: ament_cmake_core ament_flake8 ament_pyflakes fastcdr osrf_testing_tools_cpp
  1 package had stderr output: cyclonedds
  289 packages not processed
```

Edit 4:

### collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_derive@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/grid_test_target.dir/build.make:130: grid_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:451: CMakeFiles/grid_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/movable_text_test_target.dir/build.make:131: movable_text_test_target] Error 1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:481: CMakeFiles/movable_text_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/billboard_line_test_target.dir/build.make:130: billboard_line_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:337: CMakeFiles/billboard_line_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wrench_visual_test_target.dir/build.make:130: wrench_visual_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:194: CMakeFiles/wrench_visual_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_new_id@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/point_cloud_renderable_test_target.dir/build.make:130: point_cloud_renderable_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:280: CMakeFiles/point_cloud_renderable_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_derive@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_new_id@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_CTX_new_id@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_generate@UUID_1.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_derive@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/covariance_visual_test_target.dir/build.make:130: covariance_visual_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:394: CMakeFiles/covariance_visual_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to 'EVP_KDF_derive@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libSM.so: undefined reference to 'uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/line_test_target.dir/build.make:130: line_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:511: CMakeFiles/line_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/point_cloud_test_target.dir/build.make:130: point_cloud_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:164: CMakeFiles/point_cloud_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2

Failed   <<< rviz_rendering [1.15s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< rcutils [1.63s]
Aborted  <<< rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp [1.03s]
Aborted  <<< rosidl_generator_c [3.06s]

Summary: 117 packages finished [24.5s]
1 package failed: rviz_rendering
3 packages aborted: rcutils rosidl_generator_c rosidl_typesupport_introspection_cpp
1 package had stderr output: rviz_rendering
182 packages not processed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359578/colcon-build---symlink-install-can%27t-find-%27__main__%27-module;-ld:-cannot-find--lpthreads/) by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-15**:
The `pthreads` issue could be a red herring.

I'd first solve this:

```
/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/em'
```

you appear to have Anaconda installed.

Have you made sure `pip` (invoked via `rosdep`, but also manually) has installed the dependencies ROS needs for that specific interpreter, instead of your system provided one?

If it hasn't, you basically haven't installed the dependencies.

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-15**:
Updated original post with similar errors even after installing setuptools and pytest-cov

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-08-15**:
I recently built ROS 2 Foxy on Fedora 32. It looks like you are trying to install ROS 2 Dashing that was released few years ago and was targeting Fedora 30 so maybe that's why you're facing more problems.

What I did to compile Foxy is:

- Follow these instructions: https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup

  - With special attention to the section "System requirements" -> "Fedora 32, see [alternate instructions](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Fedora-Development-Setup/)"
  - replaced `python3-pep8` by `python3-pycodestyle` in the list of packages to install
- In the section "[Get the ROS2 Code](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup/#get-ros-2-code)" I had to use the repos file from https://github.com/ros2/ros2/pull/1005/files as the one from the instructions is missing a repository
- then ran `colcon build --symlink-install` successfully

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-15**:
Thanks several packages installed now, but I get a different error updated in the original post. What is `Failed   <<< cyclonedds`

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-15**:
Thanks @[marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/), now getting different errors, I also tried setting `-DBUILD_IDLC=OFF` in `cyclonedds/colcon.pkg` per [this suggestion](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/issues/332#issuecomment-556088441), now getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'Interpreter' from 'em' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em/__init__.py)`

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-15**:
Any more suggestions?

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to `EVP_KDF_ctrl@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to `EVP_KDF_derive@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/grid_test_target.dir/build.make:130: grid_test_target] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:451: CMakeFiles/grid_test_target.dir/all] Error 2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib64/libssh.so.4: undefined reference to `EVP_KDF_CTX_free@OPENSSL_1_1_1b'
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/movable_text_test_target.dir/build.make:131: movable_text_test_target] Error 1
Failed   <<< rviz_rendering
```

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-08-17**:\

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Interpreter' from 'em'

You might have the Python package `em` installed which has the same namespace as `empy` which is the packages needed by `colcon` as well as ROS 2. You need to uninstall `em` and make sure `empy` is installed. See https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/pull/370 for an improved error message in the future.

**Comment by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on 2020-08-17**:
Thanks @dirk-thomas, that was an issue but now it's all of these `undefined reference` errors, see the bottom of the original post (click 'more'). Since we have Anaconda Python and Fedora Python, I believe there could be a conflict. I tried upgrading Anaconda Python to 3.8, still same errors. I also tried using -`DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/envs/python38/bin/python -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/envs/python38/include/python3.8`
as well as:

```
echo $PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
/usr/local/bin/anaconda3/envs/python38/include/python3.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I got it going. Here are the work-arounds needed:

-Add the stanza from [this    repo](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/pull/1005/files)    to `ros2.repos`.

-Change the    option `-DBUILD_IDLC=OFF` in       `cyclonedds/colcon.pkg` per [this       suggestion](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/issues/332#issuecomment-556088441)

-Updated `$PATH` so `/usr/bin` was first to ensure Fedora's Python 3.8    was used.

Now trying to determine how to install it so multiple users can use the ROS 2 commands. Do the binaries still need to be installed? Will that work on Fedora? They all seem customized for Debian/Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) with karma: 43 on 2020-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1